The maximum distance supported between two nodes in an ESP32 based mesh network
What is the maximum distance supported between two nodes in a network implemented using the ESP-WIFI-MESH protocol developed by Espressif Systems for their ESP32 modules? The documentation mentions that this mesh networking protocol is designed to allow nodes spread over a wide physical area, both indoor and outdoor, to interconnect, but does not specify the maximum distance between nodes.

How long is a rope? Anyone telling you the range of an RF part like that is at best doing a very rough estimation. At best the might offer a line of sight range, but mesh networks are rarely ever line of sight.

So you would need to do tests in order to estimate that?

That's what I always had to do -  you can't trust any number they give you anyway, because it's just a "guesstimate". Buy a couple of prototypes, hook them up and move them around in the building, try line of sight outdoors etc etc.

Thank you sir! I'll get right on it.

Complex. Indoor or outdoor? To get decent range height at both ends needs to ensure that lowest point (often but not always mid span) is above Fresnel zone distance. (Google knows )(but start here: https://wiki2.org/en/Fresnel_zone). Aerials should be good quality and well matched to the ESPs. ensure good sized cap on power supply. Not near metal ...

... objects and ideally not near anything. A km or two should be easy. 5 to 10 km doable with due care. Contest grade trying, beam aerials or cantennas or dishes ... - more. || ESP is notoriously peaky on power consumption on transmit. 500 mA peak power spikes should be provided for.

This range can vary significantly depending on the factors like the transmit power, antenna design, environmental conditions, and any obstacles in the path of communication.
